# How to create a combo chart (bar and line) with fusioncharts using data from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, fusioncharts

I found this code online to do basically everything I was looking for except they are not using data from a MySQL database where as I am. Here is their code:

```
{
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Inventory by Product Categories",
        "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
        "plotgradientcolor": "",
        "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
        "showplotborder": "0",
        "divlinecolor": "CCCCCC",
        "showvalues": "0",
        "showcanvasborder": "0",
        "pyaxisname": "Cost of Inventory",
        "syaxisname": "Units in Inventory",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "labeldisplay": "STAGGER",
        "slantlabels": "1",
        "canvasborderalpha": "0",
        "legendshadow": "0",
        "legendborderalpha": "0",
        "showborder": "0"
    },
    "categories": [
        {
            "category": [
                {
                    "label": "Seafood",
                    "labelPadding": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Beverages",
                    "labelPadding": 12
                },
                {
                    "label": "Condiments",
                    "labelPadding": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Dairy Products",
                    "labelPadding": 12
                },
                {
                    "label": "Confections",
                    "labelPadding": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Meat/Poultry",
                    "labelPadding": 12
                },
                {
                    "label": "Grains/Cereals",
                    "labelPadding": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Produce",
                    "labelPadding": 12
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dataset": [
        {
            "seriesname": "Cost of Inventory",
            "color": "008ee4",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "13510"
                },
                {
                    "value": "12480"
                },
                {
                    "value": "12024"
                },
                {
                    "value": "11271"
                },
                {
                    "value": "10392"
                },
                {
                    "value": "5729"
                },
                {
                    "value": "5594"
                },
                {
                    "value": "3549"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "Quantity",
            "parentyaxis": "S",
            "renderas": "Line",
            "color": "f8bd19",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "701"
                },
                {
                    "value": "559"
                },
                {
                    "value": "507"
                },
                {
                    "value": "393"
                },
                {
                    "value": "386"
                },
                {
                    "value": "165"
                },
                {
                    "value": "258"
                },
                {
                    "value": "100"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This makes sense, but it's changing this JSON code to accept data from a database instead of hardcoding this that is difficult for me.

Here is the relevent part of my code:

```
<?php
        $strQuery2 = "SELECT ScrapDate, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Scrap WHERE Department = 'WE' GROUP BY ScrapDate ORDER BY ScrapDate";

        // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
        $result2 = $dbhandle->query($strQuery2) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($result2) {
                // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
                $arrData2 = array(
                "chart" => array(
                    "caption" => "WE Last Week Scrap Quantity",
                    "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
                    "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                    "borderAlpha"=> "20",
                    "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                    "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                    "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                    "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                    "showValues"=> "0",
                    "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                    "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0",
                    "xAxisName"=> "Day",
                    "yAxisName"=> "Quantity"
                )
                );

                $arrData2["data"] = array();

        // Push the data into the array

                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                array_push($arrData2["data"], array(
                "label" => $row2["ScrapDate"],
                "value" => $row2["Quantity"],
//                "link" => "deptDrillDown.php?Department=".$row["Department"]
                )
                );
                }

        $jsonEncodedData2 = json_encode($arrData2);

        $columnChart2 = new FusionCharts("column2D", "chart2" , 600, 300, "chart-2", "json", $jsonEncodedData2);

        // Render the chart
        $columnChart->render();
        $columnChart2->render();

        // Close the database connection
        $dbhandle->close();

        }
?>
```

As of right now, I can get data from the MySQL database and put it into a graph very easily. Now I want to add 1 more dataset, how do I do this?

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the console? Are you getting data back? What is the format? The Json you gave is great but you need to try and get that structure then with your data.

Comment: I guess I should have specified, I have not implemented any code to include the 3rd dataset. Currently I have a working bar graph. Now I want to add a line graph on top of my chart with a 3rd dataset I have yet to include.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically update the chart, following [methods](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html) turns very useful:

> - [getJSONData](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#getJSONData): Fetches chart data in the JSON format.
> - [setJSONData](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#setJSONData): Sets chart data in the JSON data format

A sample implementation is shown in the below snippet. The chart is initially rendered as the default `column2d` chart. Once the `Add Area` button is clicked, an area dataset gets visually updated. Similarly on clicking the `Add Line` button to add a line dataset. The `Reset` button restores to original column only visual.

```js
var visitChart,
  areaBtn = document.getElementById('area'),
  lineBtn = document.getElementById('line'),
  resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  visitChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'mscombi2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '500',
    height: '300',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Actual Revenues, Targeted Revenues & Profits",
        "subcaption": "Last year",
        "xaxisname": "Month",
        "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "theme": "fint"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
          "label": "Jan"
        }, {
          "label": "Feb"
        }, {
          "label": "Mar"
        }, {
          "label": "Apr"
        }, {
          "label": "May"
        }, {
          "label": "Jun"
        }, {
          "label": "Jul"
        }, {
          "label": "Aug"
        }, {
          "label": "Sep"
        }, {
          "label": "Oct"
        }, {
          "label": "Nov"
        }, {
          "label": "Dec"
        }]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "Actual Revenue",
        "data": [{
          "value": "16000"
        }, {
          "value": "20000"
        }, {
          "value": "18000"
        }, {
          "value": "19000"
        }, {
          "value": "15000"
        }, {
          "value": "21000"
        }, {
          "value": "16000"
        }, {
          "value": "20000"
        }, {
          "value": "17000"
        }, {
          "value": "25000"
        }, {
          "value": "19000"
        }, {
          "value": "23000"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }).render();
});
areaBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dataset,
    json = visitChart.getJSONData();
  if (!(dataset = json.dataset)) {
    dataset = json.dataset = [];
  }
  dataset.push({
    "seriesname": "Profit",
    "renderas": "area",
    "showvalues": "0",
    "data": [{
      "value": "4000"
    }, {
      "value": "5000"
    }, {
      "value": "3000"
    }, {
      "value": "4000"
    }, {
      "value": "1000"
    }, {
      "value": "7000"
    }, {
      "value": "1000"
    }, {
      "value": "4000"
    }, {
      "value": "1000"
    }, {
      "value": "8000"
    }, {
      "value": "2000"
    }, {
      "value": "7000"
    }]
  });
  visitChart.setJSONData(json);
  areaBtn.disabled = true;
});
lineBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dataset,
    json = visitChart.getJSONData();
  if (!(dataset = json.dataset)) {
    dataset = json.dataset = [];
  }
  dataset.push({
    "seriesname": "Projected Revenue",
    "renderas": "line",
    "showvalues": "0",
    "data": [{
      "value": "15000"
    }, {
      "value": "16000"
    }, {
      "value": "17000"
    }, {
      "value": "18000"
    }, {
      "value": "19000"
    }, {
      "value": "19000"
    }, {
      "value": "19000"
    }, {
      "value": "19000"
    }, {
      "value": "20000"
    }, {
      "value": "21000"
    }, {
      "value": "22000"
    }, {
      "value": "23000"
    }]
  });
  visitChart.setJSONData(json);
  lineBtn.disabled = true;
});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dataset,
    len,
    json = visitChart.getJSONData();
  if (!(dataset = json.dataset)) {
    dataset = json.dataset = [];
  }
  if ((len = dataset.length) > 1) {
    dataset.splice(1, len - 1);
  }
  visitChart.setJSONData(json);
  areaBtn.disabled = false;
  lineBtn.disabled = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
<button id='area'>Add Area</button>
<button id='line'>Add Line</button>
<button id='reset'>Reset</button>
<span id="chart-container">FusionCharts XT will load here!</span>
```

The data getting appended might be fetched from a database in a similar manner stated above.

Comment: Hi @michael let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi, that is the issue. I need to be able to do this straight from a database. this example shows how to get data already in JSON format